# (crystalline cohomology version's) Tate's conjecture for K3 surfaces

Tags: nt.number-theory, crystalline-cohomology

Let $X$ be a K3 over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. The (crystalline version's) Tate conjecture predicts:

$c_1: Pic(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow H^2_{crys}(X/W)^{\Phi=p}\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p$

is an isomorphism.

If $\lambda=1-\frac{1}{h}$ is the smallest slope of $H^2_{crys}(X/W)$, then $H^2_{crys}(X/W)$ must be isogenous to $H_{\lambda}\oplus H_1^{22-2h} \oplus H_{2-\lambda}$, where $H_\alpha$ is the F-crystal that $\Phi^t=p^s$ for $\alpha=s/t$. The $\Phi=p$ parts of the latter F-crystal apparently has rank $22-2h$, so the  $\Phi=p$ part of $H^2_{crys}(X/W)$ must also has rank $22-2h$? Which means the above conjecture is equivalent to $\rho=22-2h$ always hold true? But the later one is not true in general, as a general K3 in char $p$ should have Picard number $2$, which is usually less than $22-2h$.

Where was I wrong?

Comment: I must be apparently wrong somewhere, can someone tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you write that $2$ is strictly less than $22-2h$?

Comment: @JasonStarr A generic K3 surface should have $h=1$? I mean the locus $M_{2d}^1$ where $h=1$ is an open subset of $M_{2d}$ right? According to Huybrechts' notes

Comment: @JasonStarr I think my understanding for F-crystal must be wrong somewhere, I mean maybe isogenous F-crystals do not necessarily have the same rank for the $\Phi=p$ part. I don't know?? $H^2(X/W)$ should be isomorphic to a sub $W$-module of $H_{\lambda}\oplus H_1^{22-2h}\oplus H_{2-\lambda}$, so their $\Phi=p$ part shouldn't be different? I don't know any other examples of F-crystals

Comment: What I know about this comes from the article "Constructing rational curves on K3 surfaces" by Bogomolov, Hassett, and Tschinkel: https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3527   In that article they use Theorem 15 (due to many authors): every non-supersingular surface over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$ has even Picard rank (so at least $2$).

Comment: Also I just heard from an expert (who I will not name unless given permission) who tells me that also supersingular K3 surfaces have Picard rank 22.

Comment: @JasonStarr Is that so? Even in characteristic 2? Check Shioda's paper 'Kummer surfaces in char 2' where the author constructed a K3 with $\rho=19$

Comment: @JasonStarr But for non-supersingular K3 the equation $\rho=22-2h$ should be false in general. But I couldn't see why this doesn't contradict Tate's conjecture for the structure of its F-crystal

Comment: Elliptic curves over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ always have an extra endomorphism: the Frobenius endomorphism relative to $\mathbb{F}_q$.  So they do not satisfy the hypothesis in Shioda's article.  Shioda also considers fields of positive characteristic that are not finite fields.  Over some of these fields he produces examples of Picard rank $19$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146576/discussion-between-yuan-yang-and-jason-starr).

Comment: Perhaps what is going on is confusion about the word "generic."  The point that I am making is that *no* K3 surface over a finite field is *generic* in the sense that its (geometric) Picard group is isomorphic to the geometric Picard group of the "generic" K3 surface in the sense of the fiber over the geometric generic point for a moduli space of (polarized) K3 surfaces.

Comment: @JasonStarr I see what you mean. I should use the word 'general' rather than 'generic'. In Huybrechts' book he said "the condition $\rho(X)\geq\rho$ is not (a closed condition), it rather defines a countable union
of closed sets" and "However, many more $(X, H)$
not contained in $M_{2d}^{10}$ satisfy $\rho(X) \leq 2$, in fact the general one should have this property". So apparently in his mind the equation $\rho=22-2h$ is false in general."

Comment: @JasonStarr But this is very confusing: over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, a countable union of closed sets can cover the whole moduli space, which means it is possible that the locus $\rho=2$ in $M_{2d}^{1}$ is empty. So whether there are such K3 such that $\rho=2$ but $h=1$ is still not clear from his book.

Comment: Here is something else from Ogus' crystalline Toreli theorem for supersingular K3 paper, he said, over $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$, "the isomorphism class of a K3 crystal with $h\neq \infty$ is uniquely determined by $h$". So this means the space $\Phi=p$ is uniquely determined by $h$ and thus must have rank $22-2h$. Together with Tate's conjecture over finite fields, does this mean $\rho=22-2h$ (where $\rho$ is of course the geometric picard number) always hold? Or the F-crystal over $W(\mathbb{F}_q)$ behaves differently with F-crystals over $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_p})$?

Comment: If $\rho=22-2h$ is always true, then this formula should be written in the text book!! (Not just an inequality!!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to a phenomenon called 'hypersymmetry' (or the lack of it). The term comes from Chai and Oort, who explored this for abelian varieties. The essential point is that the category of F-isocrystals over the algebraic closure of a finite field is *not* the filtered colimit of the corresponding categories over its finite subfields.

For the simplest example, take a product of two non-isogenous ordinary elliptic curves $A = E_1\times E_2$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$. You can get such a pair by choosing two Weil $q$-numbers of weight $1$ generating distinct quadratic extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then we have (with the Tate twist on the left hand side)

$H^2_{crys}(A/W(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)(1) = \mathrm{Hom}(H^1_{crys}(E_1/W(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p),H^1_{crys}(E_2/W(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p))\oplus H^2_{crys}(E_1/W(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p))(1) \oplus H^2_{crys}(E_2/W(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p) )(1)$

Since both elliptic curves are ordinary, they have isogenous (as $F$-crystals) crystalline cohomology groups over $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p$. In particular, if you take $\varphi$-invariants, you will get a 4-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector space.

However, if you repeat this over any finite field containing the $j$-invariants of $E_1$ and $E_2$, then the crystalline Tate conjecture says that the $\varphi$-invariants will only be 2-dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}_p$, since the first Hom space should have no $\varphi$-invariant elements.

If you take the Kummer K3 surface associated with $A$, you will find a K3 surface that has the same feature: The $\varphi$-invariants in $H^2_{crys}$ over $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ will have two extra ‘transcendental’ dimensions that are not visible over any $W(\mathbb{F}_q)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer:). By the way, do you know if there is any crystalline Torelli theorem for non-supersingular K3 surfaces? For example, if two K3s over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ have isomorphic $H^2_{crys}(X/W(\mathbb{F}_q))$(respect both $\phi$ and cup-product), are these two K3s isomorphic abstractly over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$? (I am aware of a crystalline Torelli for supersingular K3s, so I wonder if a similar thing holds for non-supersingular ones)

Answer (score 1):

I see where is the problem.

First of all, the right statement of Tate conjecture is for $X$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ (not over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$!), and Tate conjecture predicts:

$c_1: Pic(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p\rightarrow H^2_{crys}(X/W(\mathbb{F}_q))^{\Phi=p}\otimes\mathbb{Q}_p$ is an isomorphism.

Secondly, Dieudonn$\acute{e}$-Manin classification only works  over algebraically closed fields like $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$, doesn't work over $\mathbb{F}_q$, and when we talk about slopes of an F-crystal $H$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, we actually mean the slopes of $H\otimes W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q})$.

Now assume the K3 crystal $H^2_{crys}(X/W(\mathbb{F}_q))$ has slopes $1-\frac{1}{h},1,1+\frac{1}{h}$, and assume it's non-supersingular.

The fact is, although the rank of $(H^2_{crys}(X/W(\mathbb{F}_q))\otimes W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}))^{\Phi=p}$ is indeed $22-2h$, the rank of $H^2_{crys}(X/W(\mathbb{F}_q))^{\Phi=p}$ can be smaller:

Here is an easy example of F-crystal over $\mathbb{F}_9$ of slope 1 rank 1 but $\Phi=p$ space is trivial:

Since $W(\mathbb{F}_9)\cong \mathbb{Z}_9$ there is an 8-th roots-of-unity $\zeta_8$ in $W(\mathbb{F}_9)$, let $H$ be the rank 1 $W(\mathbb{F}_9)$-module where $\Phi$ maps $1$ to $\zeta_8p$.

Then this F-crystal maps any $x\in W(\mathbb{F}_9)$ to $\zeta_8p\sigma(x)$, where $\sigma\in Gal(\mathbb{Q}_9/\mathbb{Q}_3)$ is the only non-trivial (Frobenius) map.

Then no element in $\mathbb{Z}_9$ satisfy $\zeta_8p\sigma(x)=px$. (This is simply because the multiplicative subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_9^{\times}$ generated by elements of the form $\sigma(x)/x$ is actually $\mu_4\times(\frac{4+3i}{5})^{\mathbb{Z}_3}$, the group of 4th-roots of unities-this is an easy computation.)

But after base change to $W(\overline{\mathbb{F}_9})$, suppose $\zeta_{16}$ is a square root of $\zeta_8$, let $x=\zeta_{16}^7$, then $\Phi(x)=px$ which means $H$ indeed has slope $1$.

Comment: Wait, but there are still problems: it seems we can always do a finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}/\mathbb{F}_{q}$ such that the rank of $(H^2_{crys}(X/W(\mathbb{F}_q))\otimes W(\mathbb{F}_{q^m}))^{\Phi=p}$ has rank $22-2h$?

Comment: Which means that $\rho=22-2h$ is still right? Because the crystalline cohomology should have base change theorems

Comment: I will regard that $\rho=22-2h$ is true. Because I couldn't find any reason that it is wrong.